# Diferéncias en definir una constante usando define() o const en PHP

Tags: php

Veo que las nuevas versiones de PHP para definir una constante es mejor usar `const` en lugar de `define` me pregunto que ventajas y desventajas incluyen ambos métodos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He tenido que documentarme mejor.

Efectivamente, desde PHP 5.0.3, ambos métodos pueden ser usados para definir constantes. En el caso de `define()` puede ser usado en cualquier punto de la ejecución, caso contrario de `const` que debe ser usado solo en el ámbito de nivel más alto. Esto significa, que `const` no puede ser usado dentro de estructuras de control o funciones.

Hay más información sobre ello en [la web oficial de PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php)

Answer (score 1):

Decir queda también que **const** es **dos** veces más rapida que **define()**.
**const** define constantes en tiempo de compilación, no se puede usar como una constante global a no ser que sea fuera de la clase y también soporta ARRAYS mientras que **define** no los soporta todavía en la versión PHP 5.0

Comment: define acepta array como argumento a partir de la versión 7.0.0 de PHP.

Comment: Si , por eso ha puesto hasta PHP 5.0